# Scaling bitmap into EMF via System.Drawing with specific width im millimeters?

Tags: c#, system.drawing, metafile

I have a couple of bitmaps/pngs (screenshots), which I would like to "wrap" in EMFs having a specific width in millimeters (and a proportional height).  Ideally, I would also want to add some overlays (text & rectangles).

Creating and saving an EMF seems to generally work fine, but I am unable to get any of the scaling right.

Here is my code:

```
var sourceBitmap = Image.FromFile(@"C:\temp\example.png");
Metafile metafile;
var aspectRatio = (float)sourceBitmap.Height / (float)sourceBitmap.Width;
var size = new Size(200, (int) (200*aspectRatio));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var offScreenBufferGraphics = Graphics.FromHwndInternal(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        IntPtr deviceContextHandle = offScreenBufferGraphics.GetHdc();
        metafile = new Metafile(stream, deviceContextHandle, new RectangleF(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height), MetafileFrameUnit.Millimeter, EmfType.EmfPlusOnly); // this allocates one gdi object
        offScreenBufferGraphics.ReleaseHdc();
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(metafile))
        {
            graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;

            // may need to do something with ScaleTransform here??
            var metafileHeader = metafile.GetMetafileHeader();
            float sx = metafileHeader.DpiX / graphics.DpiX;
            float sy = metafileHeader.DpiY / graphics.DpiY;
            graphics.ScaleTransform(sx, sy);

            graphics.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            var pen1 = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue));
            var pen2 = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red));
            graphics.DrawRectangle(pen1, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
            graphics.DrawLine(pen2, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
            graphics.DrawLine(pen2, 0, size.Height, size.Width, 0);

            graphics.Dispose();
        }
    }
}


// save as a metafile
IntPtr metafileHandle = metafile.GetHenhmetafile();
var result = Gdi32.CopyEnhMetaFile(metafileHandle, @"C:\temp\example.emf");
if (result.ToInt32() == 0)
{
    var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    throw new Win32Exception(error);
}
Gdi32.DeleteEnhMetaFile(result);
Gdi32.DeleteEnhMetaFile(metafileHandle);
```

Neither are the rectangle and diagonal lines correct, nor is the source bitmap correctly filled into the EMF. 
What am I doing wrong here?

The final EMF should be embedded into a Word document - hence the specific width. 
Note that I do not want to downsize the bitmaps and include these directly, since I would likely loose quality this way. Also note that I do not want to include the full bitmap in Word and have it adjust/scale the image, as I need to use {includepicture} which does not seem to reliably work with scaling.

Comment: graphics.DrawImage will honor the bimap's dpi. - Maybe setting the dpi of the sourceBitmap will help. By default it will be the screen dpi, which may be quite off. Use Bitmap.SetDpi !

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, the rectangle and diagonal lines are correct.

After changed(swaped param `destRect` and `srcRect`) the following code

```
graphics.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

to

```
graphics.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

The source bitmap correctly filled into the EMF.